# How To Press "OK" When Printing in SAP from Excel (SAP GUI Script)

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Here we go again at the old question of pressing "OK" that has been very frustrating to solve.

I recorded a Script in SAP to print a document but somehow when it opens an new printer dialog box I have to click manually "Ok" and the script is not showing me what window or button it is.
Here is the Script and the dialog window[image]:

```
Sub SAP_PrntLgBestListe_Conv()


If Not IsObject(SAPapplication) Then
  Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
  Set SAPapplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(SAPconnection) Then
  Set SAPconnection = SAPapplication.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(SAPSession) Then
  Set SAPSession = SAPconnection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(wscript) Then
  wscript.ConnectObject SAPSession, "on"
  wscript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If

With SAPSession
 .StartTransaction "MB52"
 .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press
 .findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").Text = "DARASIC"
 .findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
 .findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 1
 .findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "1"
 .findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell
 .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
 .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[86]").press
 .findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[13]").press       'Spool-Order sent to SAP-Printer LOCL - Printer window appears

' Here needs to click OK on printer window

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This dialog is not displayed by SAP GUI, so you can't make it work with SAP GUI Scripting. So, the question is not about automating this dialog with SAP GUI Scripting, but with VBA.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/290179/at-end-of-script-new-print-dialog-box-open-i-want-.html) BTW, the code your showing is not VBA.

Comment: You have to open another Workbook with monitoring code, to identify the dialog and click on the desired button. I do this way, using Windows API. The current Workbook creates another one, then insert the code in a module,  and runs it... But the code is quite extensive and it's out of bonds to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some programs to check the object's location (go with API). I'm using Window Detective. An example of your code should be something like this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function findWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function findWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function sendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    
Function print_window()

Dim saveWindowPrint As Long
check_agn_open_window:

    '--- find Print Window
    saveWindowPrint = findWindow(vbNullString, "Drucken")
            
    '--- check if saveWindow is open
    If saveWindowPrint = 0 Then: GoTo check_agn_open_window
       
    '--- Get Save button
    buttonOK = findWindowEx(saveWindowPrint, 0, "Button", "OK")
    
    '--- click on the save button
    sendMessage buttonOK, &HF5&, 0, 0
End Function
```

And after that, you need to go to with saving window. So, use also API for this.

Comment: Hi Lukasz
Hell yeah... This is working perfect.  Thanks a lot buddy. Can you briefly explain to me excatly how this API is working or why are there so many "ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2...". Other than that great job buddy, Twoje zdrowie.